# Beautiful Soup - finding all classes which contain a know strin

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I was trying to extract the string '£150,000' from this HTML code by identifying the string 'Purchase Price' within the class since the same class is used more than once

```
<div class="row mb-sm-1 property-header-row">

                 <div class="prop-capital-fields property-header-col col-6"><h3>£150,000</h3> 
                                            <p class="label-paragraph">
                                                Purchase Price
                                            </p>
                 </div> 

                 <div class="prop-capital-fields property-header-col col-6"><h3>£180,000</h3> 
                                            <p class="label-paragraph">
                                                Market Value
                                            </p>
                 </div> 

                 <div class="prop-capital-fields property-header-col col-6"><h3>£1,185</h3> 
                                            <p class="label-paragraph">
                                                Potential Cashflow PCM
                                            </p>
                 </div>
```

So I wrote the following code

```
property_ = soup.find(class_="properties-content-body col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7")
for a in property_.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'prop-capital-fields property-header-col col-6'}, text="Purchase Price"):
    purchase_price_list.append(a)
print(purchase_price_list)
```

but all I get is a blank list

I've tried many other things but I'm pretty sure I just don't know the correct way to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer:

```
for a in property_.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'prop-capital-fields property-header-col col-6'}):
    b = a.find('p').text.replace("\n", "").strip()
    c = a.find('h3').text.strip()
    if(b=='Purchase Price'):
        purchase_price_list.append(c)
```